# how to delete an entire directory with Pyside2?

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I have a QFileSystemModel and can delete empty directory with **QFileSystemModel.rmdir(index)**.

Is there a way to delete non-empty directory with Pyside2?

I can **shutil.rmtree()** delete non-empty directory, but since I use Qt, I tend to use the Qt method. if it existed.

Comment: I have never used QFileSystemModel, but after a glance at rmdir I haven't seen anything that suggests that it only removes empty directories. Are you sure that it isn't an issue with insufficient permissions of one of the items *within* the directory?

Comment: I found a solution: QDir.removeRecursively()

Comment: @g2m.agent QFileSystemModel's `rmdir` is the same as [`QDir.rmdir()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#rmdir): "The directory must be empty for rmdir() to succeed". Since you've already solved it, I suggest you to create your own answer and explain the difference with links to the related documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is outside of QFileSystemModel. use
[QDir.removeRecursively()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QDir.html?highlight=qdir#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QDir.removeRecursively)

```py
def del_folder(self, checked, index):
    if not index.isValid():
        return

    model = index.model()
    path = model.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
    dir1 = QtCore.QDir(path)
    dir1.removeRecursively() # remove all.
```